# Java program freezes when using wait and notifyAll

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm trying to get into the nitty gritty of understanding how wait and notifyAll work and have hit a roadblock.

This program downloads a long text document, starts multiple threads to count characters and then outputs the count totals.

I'm using wait and notifyAll to control the thread execution so that they are completed in alphabetical order. Here's the code. I'll follow with an explanation of the problem.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  //code that reads in the data

LongTask a = new LongTask(buffer, 'a', "Thread_a", 0);
    a.start();

LongTask b = new LongTask(buffer, 'b', "Thread_b", 1);
    b.start();

//Repeat code for all other characters

a.join();

System.out.println("Alphabet count is: " + SharedResults.getResults());
```

LongTask class contains constructor and run()

```
public class LongTask extends Thread {
//Instance variables created here

//LongTask constructor
public LongTask (StringBuffer buffer, char target, String name, int turn)
{
    super(name);
    this.sharedData = sharedData;
    inputData = buffer;
    this.target = target;   
    this.turn = turn;
}


//Run method iterates through input data and counts matching characters, 
//then calls addToResults
public synchronized void run()
{
    //Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    String name = this.getName();
    int runTurn = this.turn;
    System.out.println(name + " running - Turn " + runTurn);
    Integer count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length(); i++) {
        if (inputData.charAt(i) == target) {
        count ++;   
        }
    }
    ResultsEntry newResult = new ResultsEntry(count, target);
    SharedResults.addToResults(newResult, turn);
    }
}
```

SharedResults class adds results to Array. addToResults method performs this action and controls the synchronization.

```
public class SharedResults extends Thread{
//Code that creates array
//Code for SharedResults constructor

public synchronized static void addToResults(ResultsEntry newResult, int turn)
{   
    Integer resultsCount =  newResult.getCount();
    char resultsTarget = newResult.getTarget();
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

    /*
     * Turn number is compared to the size of the results array to control the
     * order of execution. 
     */
    while (turn != results.size()){ 
        try {
            System.out.println("Wait printout");
            t.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    } 
    System.out.println(t.getName() + " is adding " + newResult);
    SharedResults input = new SharedResults(resultsCount, resultsTarget);
    System.out.println("Cumulative Results are " + results);    
    t.notifyAll();      
    }
```

Here's what I'm seeing when I watch this step through in Debug.
-Input executes and all LongTask threads start

(Thread_a should be the first thread to execute addToResults)

-Some threads (not Thread_a) hit the while evaluation of addToResults and do not proceed

-Thread_a hits the while evaluation and fully executes. (Now it should be Thread_b's turn)

-Thread_e executes the "Wait printout" (just a debugging feature that tells me when a thread is waiting) and then the program hangs.

It looks to me like I haven't set up wait correctly. The program actually worked (or appeared to be) correctly until I added in the sysout. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: How locking works here is confusing. If you use locks to protect shared data structures (where the data structure uses locking to restrict access to itself) instead of having locking done by threads it can be less of a mess.

Comment: Re, "I'm using wait and notifyAll to control the thread execution so that they are completed in alphabetical order."  That sounds like you are starting your journey in the wrong direction.  Any time you force threads to do things in a particular order, you are subverting the very idea of threads, which is to do things _concurrently_ (i.e., in no particular order.)

Comment: `public synchronized void run()`---this is _always_ a bad idea.

Comment: Calling `t.wait()` and `t.notifyAll()` may yield surprising results if `t` refers to a `Thread` object.  The `Thread` class uses `t.wait()` and `t.notify()` for its own purposes.

Comment: I changed the variable for the Thread name to thread, so now the method calls are thread.wait() and thread.notifyAll(). That got each thread to at least execute addToResults. It looks like the threads that hit wait() never start again, even after thread_a hits notifyAll().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question,

This was covered in [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817437/trying-to-get-guarded-blocks-to-work)

The problem is that notifyAll() notify all of **that object's** threads that are waiting. Because I was calling wait() on each thread, the notifyAll() from another thread wasn't notifying any of the other threads.

As suggested by the linked post, I created a static synchronized object and called the wait and notify methods on that object. The resulting code looked like this:
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

```
public static void addToResults(ResultsEntry newResult, int turn)
{   
    Integer resultsCount =  newResult.getCount();
    char resultsTarget = newResult.getTarget();
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();

    /*
     * Turn number is compared to the size of the results array to control the
     * order of execution. 
     */
    synchronized (LOCK){
        while (turn != results.size()){
            try {
                System.out.println(thread.getName() + " is waiting");
                LOCK.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
            System.out.println(thread.getName() + " is adding " + newResult);
            SharedResults input = new SharedResults(resultsCount, resultsTarget);
            System.out.println("Cumulative Results are " + results);    
            LOCK.notifyAll();   
        }
        }
```

Thanks to all who commented!